# how to create a jquery toggle using existing html code

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

```
<div class="rsvp">
     <div class="block">

        <span class="rsvpNote">
        <h4 class="rsvpTitle">
            <a href="#" class="blockExpand" click="toggleRSVP(this); return false;"><span class="arrow"></span>RSVP</a>
        </h4> </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Hello I have this code to work with and I need to make a toggle with Jquery however, I cannot make it work. Also, is there a way to customize the button that will make up this toggle. 
Content will follow underneath these DIV. Thanks.

Comment: what else have u tried

Comment: i tried all possible codes and I cannot find a way to customize the button. I just want a button that will slide up and down when you click on it showing the information when you click on it.

Comment: you mean that the button should slide down or the information should

Comment: 2 seconds on Google, and you would have found this : http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Yes, I found this but I'm not sure exactly how to amend the code to match my existing code. I'm a student and I'm learning how to do this type of work.

Comment: Avarind30790, when you click the button i want the information to slide down when you click the button again i want the information to slide up with the button and disappear per-say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="click">
    <div id="info">This is what you are expecting or may not , but im doing this just for fun</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#click").click(function () {
      $("#info").toggle('slow');
    });
```

CSS:

```
#info{
    width:200px;
    background-color:#9494B8;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}
```

See the
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VE8CP/)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I Finally got it working thanks to this code!

Comment: you can select my answer

Comment: I have one last question. When I refresh my browser the toggle does not remain close. Is there a way to make sure the toggle remains close until is activated by the button?

Comment: defaultly it wont display the message

Comment: on refreshing, the message to be displayed won't show up . What else u need in this