# toggle does not remain close, i have to click on the button for the toggle to close up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#click").click(function () {
    $("#info").slideToggle('slow');
    });

    });

    </script>
```

this is the html code

```
        <h4 class="rsvpTitle">


        <a href="#" id="click" class= "blockExpand"> <span class="arrow"></span>RSVP</a>
        </h4>           
        <div id="info" class="expandContent">  

            <form id="formmail method="post" action="form_handler.php">

                <label class="response" for="response">Will you be joining us?</label><br>
                <span style="margin-left:121px;">   
                <input type="radio" name="response" value="I'll be there with bells on!" id="response">I'll be there with bells on!</span>
                <br>
```

I have this code for a toggle effect. However, the toggle does not remain close, I want the toggle to remain close until someone clicks on the button to release the toggle. any ideas? is the code well written?

Comment: Where is the Button ??

Comment: I think he meant the anchor

Comment: did u missed to [LOOK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292079/how-to-create-a-jquery-toggle-using-existing-html-code/17293670#17293670) at the css i gave you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to add display: none; to #info and e.preventDefault() to your js

examples: 
http://jsbin.com/oxuqus/2/ OR 
http://jsfiddle.net/kB2fc/

CSS:

```
#info {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#click").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#info").slideToggle('slow');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your CSS

```
#info {
   display : none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8XnJt/)

(jsFiddle)

### Explanation

The element is not hidden at the document `load` event. You must hide it with `display:none;` in your CSS to ensure it is not visible without user interaction.

---

### Solution

Add the following to your `CSS`:

```
#info
{
    display:none;
}
```

### NOTE

You are not closing your `input` and `span` elements ! Add the closing tags:

```
<input type="radio" name="response" value="I'll be there with bells on!" id="response">I'll be there with bells on!
</input>
</span>
```